# Laravel 5 dont take changes made in PhpStorm via sftp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

Good time of day! I have strange problem with Laravel 5 and PhpStorm. I edit files on my server in PhpStorm via sftp. I can see with ssh that files actualy changed on remote server, but when i open page in browser i see old version without any changes. In the other hand, if i edit files directly on server via ssh, it all works! In both cases files on server changes, but only in second case my corrections have effect.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload
```

on your server to get your changed files involved.

Laravel creates compiled files to speed up performance.